# What's the importance of the Tablets being written with G-d's finger?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-ki-tisa

> "וַיִּתֵּן אֶל־מֹשֶׁה כְּכַלֹּתוֹ לְדַבֵּר אִתּוֹ בְּהַר סִינַי
>   שְׁנֵי לֻחֹת הָעֵדֻת לֻחֹת אֶבֶן **כְּתֻבִים בְּאֶצְבַּע אֱלֹהִים**׃" ([Ex 31:18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.31.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
>
> He gave Moses the two tablets of the Pact, stone tablets inscribed with the finger of God.

What's the importance of "G-d's finger", why it wasn't enough writing "tablets inscribed by God"? Was there anything special about the inscription it had to be made with a finger?

Comment: It's a very strong anthropomorphism, emphasizing the importance of the inscription, IMHO.  He of course doesn't have a finger, but what else would He write with, a pen/stylus/burning almond branch/etc? His "breath", which he caused Man to live with? A "toe"?  Finger seems proper to me, again, IMHO.

Comment: @Gary I didn't want to take this path, only why "G-d's finger" is better than "by G-d", or "G-d's hand" or arm which we already met in Egypt?

Answer (score 1):

Rav Hirsch ends his comment on [Ki Sisa 31:18](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9892#v=18&showrashi=true)

> The given Law is unchangeable, we its receivers and observers, are to
>   develop ourselves on it, and about it and through it in constant
>   progress. כתובים באצבע אלוהים: directly as the work of Hashem Himself
>   as *the heavens the work of His Fingers*, [Tehillim
>   8:4](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16229/jewish/Chapter-8.htm#v=4&showrashi=true),
>   as clearly bearing witness to Hashem, as the miracles in Egypt pointed
>   to *the Finger of Hashem* [Vaera 8:15](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9869#v=15&showrashi=true)

Thus, this is the anthopomorphism that is most correct showing the *writing* as the direct action of Hashem. It creates the image of Hashem causing the action being described.

Comment: Nothing in a "finger" shows more involvement than a "hand". I personally can't connect with R' Hirsch's ideas as they only target a certain (probably very illiterate and ignorant) audience. His claims are indecipherable to me, such as *"The given Law is unchangeable"*. 2. Only one miracle was compared to G-d's finger - the lice AFAIK. 3 The last sentence does not make sense - what creates the image of G-d?

Comment: @AlBerko When speaking of *writing* one envisages the finger doing the *work* of creating the letters on the luchos. The miracle of the lice is what caused the magicians to *see* the Finger of Hashem. Once that was acknowledged, all the  miracles were already seen in that way. The quote from Rav Hirsch was the end of a very long commentary explaining the usage of the *Finger* as the appropriate metaphor. The metaphor is the technical use of *fine motor skills* to accomplish an action. *Hand* is a larger broader action. As a result, *Finger* is more appropriate for *writing*.

Comment: But what does it add to the understanding? What was lacking if it said: "the Tablet inscribed by G-d". Would you wonder - G-d's finger or G-d's toe?